# ¿Cómo hago para almacenar números menores e iguales a 5 y comparar si son menores e iguales a 5? ciclo for C

Tags: c, algoritmos, ciclos

La idea de este programa es que me imprima los números menores e iguales a 5, pero el problema que tengo es: ¿cómo hago para almacenar los números menores e iguales a 5 y luego comparar si son menores e iguales a 5?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, cn=0, contador=0, menor;

  printf("\nIngrese cuantos numeros desea comparar:\n");
  scanf("%d",&cn);
  printf("Ingrese los numeros:\n");

  for(contador=1;contador<=cn;contador++) {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<menor && n<5 && menor==5) {
      menor=n;
    }
  }

  printf("\nLos numeros menores e iguales a 5 son: %d",menor);
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta será mas legible si formateas el código.

Comment: Como hago eso?..

Comment: Selecciona la sección de código y presiona sobre el icono `{}` del editor, o simplemente tabula con 4 espacios

Comment: Si no puedes usar arreglos te sugiero que coloques esa condicion en tu pregunta, de esa forma alguien que quiera dar su solucion no tendra que buscar en los comentarios de otra respuesta, y asi sería mas claro. porque la pregunta dice claramente que quieres ALMACENAR para despues imprimir

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución, sin *arreglos*, que usa la recursividad:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test( int rem ) {
  int n;

  if( rem ) {
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    test( rem - 1 );

    if( n >= 5 )
      printf( "%d ", n );
  } else {
    printf( "\nNumeros iguales o mayores que 5:\n" );
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  int cn;

  printf( "\nIngrese cuantos numeros desea comparar:\n" );
  scanf( "%d", &cn );
  printf( "Ingrese los numeros:\n" );

  test( cn );

  printf( "\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Esta solución **tienen un límite** en la cantidad de números que puede manejar, que depende de la plataforma. No obstante, debería de *aguantar* mas de `1000` números sin problemas.

El *truco* está en el orden de las operaciones dentro de la función `test( )`.

1. Si no hay que pedir mas números, retornamos. Cortamos la recursividad.
2. Pedimos el número, que se guarda en una variable local; es decir, usamos **la pila** del sistema como *arreglo*.
3. Al retornar, comprobamos si el número en el nivel de anidamiento actual es `>= 5`. De ser el caso, lo muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir solo los que sean menores solo tienes que añadir dentro del bucle un printf con la condición necesaria. En este caso

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  int n, cn;
  int i = 0;

  printf("\nIngrese cuantos numeros desea comparar:\n");
  scanf("%d",&cn);
  printf("Ingrese los numeros:\n");

  for(i=0;i<cn;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<=5) {
      printf("El número %d es menor que 5 \n",n);
    }
  }

}
```

Para hacerlo con los números almacenados primero deberías crear un array de enteros con la cantidad de números que te pase el usuario arr[cn], después almacenarlos cuando te los pase por pantalla.

```
for(i=0; i < cn;i++){

  scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

}
```

y después recorrer ese array con otro for y comprobar con una condición if cuáles son los menores e imprimirlos.

Hace tiempo que no programo en c, el código puede estar mal  pero la idea es esa. Saludos y suerte!

Comment: si pero solo puedo usar ciclos, no puedo usar arreglos.. sino lo hago con un arreglo y listo jaja ! Gracias igual

Comment: entonces con un simple
 if(n<=5){
  printf(%i,n)
} 
en el bucle puedes imprimir los números

Comment: y eso lo guardo en una variable?

Comment: en ese caso cambia el printf donde asignas   menor=n  y vas imprimiendo a como va introduciendo los números el usuario

Comment: la variable ya la guardas cuando lees los números añade la condición debajo e imprime, la variable cambiará mientras vaya leyendo los demás números.

Comment: a ver, lo voy a probar

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta con el código que te comento, saludos